# ABC-metrics & measuring python-code quality

Tags: library, python, code-analysis

is there a library for python evaluation of code complexity that implements [ABC-metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Software_Metric) (Assignment Branch Condition)?